# How to add an tokenizer exception for whitespaces in Spacy language models

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, whitespace, tokenize, spacy

The following is my code where I take an user input.

```
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
text = input("please enter your text or words here")
doc = nlp(text)
print([t.text for t in doc])
```

If the user input the text as Deep Learning, the text is broken into

```
('Deep', 'Learning')
```

How to add an whitespace exception in nlp? such that the output is like below

```
(Deep Learning)
```

Comment: Can the user input something like, " I like deep learning" ?

Comment: yes it can be. It can also be "looking for cyber security experts" . In this case too I would ideally want "cyber security" together.

Answer (score 0):

The raw text from the user input is split on whitespace characters, similar to text.split(' '). Then, the tokenizer processes the text from left to right. On each substring, it performs two checks:

1. Does the substring match a tokenizer exception rule? For example, "don't" does not contain whitespace, but should be split into two tokens, "do" and "n't", while "U.K." should always remain one token.
2. Can a prefix, suffix or infix be split off? For example punctuation like commas, periods, hyphens or quotes.

So if your user types in: `Looking for Deep Learning experts`

It will be tokenized as: `('Looking', 'for, 'Deep', 'Learning', 'experts')`

Spacy does not know that `Deep Learning` is an entity on it's own. If you want spaCy to recognize `Deep Learning` as a single entity, you need to teach it. If you have a predefined list of words that you would want spaCy to recognize as a single entity, you can use `PhraseMatcher` to do that.

You can check the details on how to use `PhraseMatcher` [here](https://spacy.io/api/phrasematcher)

---

**UPDATE** - Reply to OP's comment below

I do not think there is a way spaCy can know about the entity you are looking for without being trained in the context of your domain or being provided a predefined subset of the entities.

The only solution I can think of is to use an annotation tool to teach spaCy
    - Take a subset of your user inputs and annotate them manually (you can use the prodigy tool by the makers of spaCy or [Brat](http://brat.nlplab.org) - it's free)
    - Use the annotations to train a new or existing NER model. Details on training a model can be found [here]([here](https://spacy.io/usage/training#section-ner)

Given a text like "Looking for Deep Learning experts", you would annotate "Deep Learning" with a label such as "FIELD". Then train a new entity type, 'FIELD'.

Once you have trained the model in the context, spaCy will learn to detect entities of interest.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but it does not solve the issue above. I have tried PhraseMatcher. It's scope is good, if you have predefined list of words. In my case the list of words could be dynamic and expanding always.